# How would I Display User Data In 2 Rows

Tags: html, mysql

I am sorry, I don't know how I could ask this question. I have a Members page which displays info of the members. However I can only manage to get it as a list going down, I would like to display something like this:

[image: Member Table]

This is my current code that I am using to display my member sheet:

```
</table>

<table width='302' height="40px" border='0' style="background-color: #F5F5F5;padding: 2px 5px;border: 1px solid #DEDEDE; border-radius: 5px;">
<tr>
<td align="left" width="151" height='38px'><font size='2px'><?php echo '' . ucfirst ($row['user_n']) . '' ?></font></td>
<td align="left" width="153" ><font size='2px'><?php echo ''. ucfirst ($row['b_name']) . '' ?></font></td>
<td align="left" width="89"><?php $timestamp = strtotime($row['login_time']); if($timestamp >= time()-1200) { echo "<img src='../includes/images/online.png'>"; } else {echo "<img src='../includes/images/offline.png'"; } ?></td>
<td align="left" width="65"><?php if($row['premium'] == "1") { echo "<img src='../includes/images/premium.png'>"; } else {echo "<img src='../includes/images/npremium.png'>"; }?></td>
<td align="left" width="98" ><font size='2px'><?php echo '' . $row['date'] . '' ?></font></td>
<td align="left" width="52"><center><?php if($row['watched'] == "1") { echo "<img src='../includes/images/red.png'>"; } else {echo "<img src='../includes/images/tick.png'>"; }?></center></td>
</tr>

</table>
```

I'm sorry, I am not the best at explaining things.

Answer (score 0):

i am not familiar with php.
but using this logic it should work for you.
You should have a counter that increments each time you display a member.
If the counter is zero print out new `<tr>` tag.
if the counter mod 2 = zero print out new `</tr><tr>` tags...
and then for each member just put them in `<td></td>` tags...
hope that helps.

Comment: I still do not understand what you mean.

Comment: if you mod and remainder is zero, it means you have printed out 2 members and so you print out `</tr></tr>` tags to end the current row and start a new row, and do that for every 2 members.